# CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint is slow on iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, ipad-3

I have a custom view (inherited from `UIView`) in my app. The custom view overrides

`- (void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect`

The problem is: the `drawRect:` executes many times longer on iPad 3 than on iPad 2 (about 0.1 second on iPad 3 and 0.003 second on iPad 2). It's about 30 times slower.

Basically, I am using some pre-created layers and draw them in the `drawRect:`. The last call

```
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointZero, m_currentLayer);
```

takes most of the time (about 95% of total time in `drawRect:`)

What might be slowing things so much and how should I fix the cause?

UPDATE:

There are no threads directly involved. I do call `setNeedsDisplay:` in one thread and `drawRect:` gets called from another but that's it. The same goes for locks (there are no locks used).

The view gets redrawn in response to touches (it's a coloring book app). On iPad 2 I get reasonable delay between a touch and an update of the screen. I want to achieve the same on iPad 3.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps the fact that your pixels have suddenly quadrupled in amount has something to do with it (retina display and all).

Comment: @borrrden I think you are right and there is supposed to be much work to do on iPad 3 but the whole process has become about 30 times slower .

Comment: I don't think anyone can venture a reasonable guess with just this information to go on.  Is any part of this using multiple threads?  Mutex locks?  Also why is this a problem for you?  Does your view redraw often?  If so, why?  DrawLayerAtPoint is likely to always be the heaviest function (it is in my app as well, though I use an iPad 2 so I can't vouch for its speed on a 3rd gen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the iPad 3 is definitely slower in a lot of areas.  I have a theory about this.  [Marco Arment noted](http://twitter.com/marcoarment/statuses/181167414636056576) that the method `renderInContext` is ridiculously slow on the new iPad.  I also found this to be the case when trying to create a magnifying glass for a custom text view.  In the end I had to forego `renderInContext` for custom Core Graphics drawing.

I've also been having problem hitting the dreaded `wait_fences` errors on my core graphics drawing here: [Only on new iPad 3: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938328/only-on-new-ipad-3-wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003/10938889#10938889).

This is what I've figured out so far.  The iPad 3 obviously has 4 times the pixels to drive.  This can cause problems in two place:

1. First, the CPU.  All core graphics drawing is done by the CPU.  In the case of rotational events, if the CPU takes too long to draw, it hits the `wait_fences` error, which I believe is simply a call that tells the device to wait a little longer to actually perform the rotation, thus the delay.
2. Transferring images to the GPU.  The GPU obviously handles the retina resolution just fine (see Infinity Blade 2).  But when core graphics draws, it draws its images directly to the GPU buffers to avoid memcpy.  However, either the GPU buffers haven't changes since the iPad 2 or they just didn't make them large enough, because it's remarkably easy to overload those buffers.  When that happens, I believe the CPU writes the images to standard memory *and then copies them to the GPU when the GPU buffers can handle it*.  This, I think is what causes the performance problems.  That extra copy is time consuming with so many pixels and slows things down considerably.

To avoid memcpy I recommend several things:

1. Only draw what you need.  Avoid drawing anything offscreen at all costs.  If you're drawing a large view, but only display part of that view (subviews covering it, for example) try to find a way to only draw what is visible.
2. If you have to draw a large view, consider breaking the view up in to parts either as subviews or sublayers (probably sublayers in your case).  And only redraw what you need.  Take the notability app, for example.  When you zoom in, you can literally watch it redraw one square at a time.  Or in safari you can watch it update squares as you scroll.  Unfortunately, I haven't had to do this so I'm uncertain of the methodology.
3. Try to keep your drawings simple.  I had an awesome looking custom core text view that had to redraw on every character entered.  Very slow.  I changed the background to simple white (in core graphics) and it sped up well.  Even better would be for me to not redraw the background.

I would like to point out that my theory is conjecture.  Apple doesn't really explain what exactly they do.  My theory is just based on what they have said and how the iPad responds as well as my own experimentation.

***UPDATE***

So Apple has now released the 2012 WWDC Developer videos.  They have two videos that may help you (requires developer account):

1. [iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766)
2. [iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animation](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766)

One thing they talk about I think may help you is using the method: `setNeedsDisplayInRect:(CGRect)rect`.  Using this method instead of the normal `setNeedsDisplay` and making sure that your `drawRect` method only draws the rect given to it can greatly help performance.  Personally, I use the function: `CGContextClipToRect(context, rect);` to clip my drawing only to the rect provided.

As an example, I have a separate class I use to draw text directly to my views using Core Text.  My UIView subclass keeps a reference to this object and uses it to draw it's text rather than use a UILabel.  I used to refresh the entire view (`setNeedsDisplay`) when the text change. Now I have my CoreText object calculate the changed CGRect and use `setNeedsDisplayInRect` to only change the portion of the view that contains the text.  This really helped my performance when scrolling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it's a valuable piece of information even though I used another source of advice in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using approach described in @Kurt Revis [answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10424635/249690).

I minimized number of layers used, added `UIImageView` and set its image to an `UIImage` wrapping my `CGImageRef`. Please read the mentioned answer to get more details about the approach.

In the end my application become even simpler than before and works with almost identical speed on iPad 2 and iPad 3.